# How to produce monthly count when given a date range in pandas?

Tags: pandas, date, date-range

I have a dataframe that records users, a label, and the start and end date of them being labelled as such
e.g.

| user | label | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 2018-01-01 | 2018-10-01 |
| 2 | x | 2019-05-10 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | y | 2019-04-01 | 2022-04-20 |
| 1 | b | 2018-10-01 | 2020-05-08 |

etc

where each row is for a given user and a label; a user appears multiple times for different labels

I want to get a count of users for every month for each label, such as this:

| date | count_label_x | count_label_y | count_label_b | count_label_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01 | 10 | 0 | 20 | 5 |
| 2018-02 | 2 | 5 | 15 | 3 |
| 2018-03 | 20 | 6 | 8 | 3 |

etc

where for instance for the first entry of the previous table, that user should be counted once for every month between his start and end date. The problem boils down to this and since I only have a few labels I can filter labels one by one and produce one output for each label. But how do I check and count users given an interval?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) combined with [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) to generate the active months, then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='nunique'` to aggregate the unique user (if you want to count the duplicated users use `aggfunc='count'`):

```
out = (df
   .assign(period=[pd.date_range(a, b, freq='M').to_period('M')
                   for a,b in zip(df['start_date'], df['end_date'])])
   .explode('period')
   .pivot_table(index='period', columns='label', values='user',
                aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0)
)
```

output:

```
label    b  x  y
period          
2018-01  0  1  0
2018-02  0  1  0
2018-03  0  1  0
2018-04  0  1  0
2018-05  0  1  0
...
2021-12  0  0  1
2022-01  0  0  1
2022-02  0  0  1
2022-03  0  0  1
```

##### handling NaT

if you have the same start/end and want to count the value:

```
out = (df
   .assign(period=[pd.date_range(a, b, freq='M').to_period('M')
                   for a,b in zip(df['start_date'], df['end_date'])])
   .explode('period')
   .assign(period=lambda d: d['period'].fillna(d['start_date'].dt.to_period('M')))
   .pivot_table(index='period', columns='label', values='user',
                aggfunc='nunique', fill_value=0)
)
```

Comment: hey thanks, that seems to be it. I have two questions: why did you use nunique? After exploding the period column, I understand that each row will be unique w.r.t the pair username-period - However, If I use count, which seems more logical to me, I get slighlt different figures (nunique sum: 405050, count sum 405562) - the latter is equal to the number of rows of the df with the exploded period without the NaT.

My other question is about the NaT: these are produced because the start and end date are equal. I could extract the yy-mm and replace the NaT, but can this be prevented beforehand?

Comment: @henrycmcjo to get the count of unique users per period, if you want to count duplicates use `count` instead. Let me check for the NaT

Comment: ok I got it re nunique; I was using a df filtered for one label just to check your code and for users that changed label and then the label was switched back within the same month then that creates duplicates